# Mongo retrieve all values of a specific field including duplicates as list

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I have the following data which I am querying on:

```
   [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "domainName": "test1.com",
        "hosting": "hostgator.com",
        "to": "nanjing",
        "travelDate": "09/06/2022",
        "trainNumber": 123
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "domainName": "test2.com",
        "hosting": "aws.amazon.com",
        "to": "beijing",
        "travelDate": "09/02/2022",
        "trainNumber": 123
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "domainName": "test3.com",
        "hosting": "aws.amazon.com"
      },
      {
        "_id": 4,
        "domainName": "test4.com",
        "hosting": "hostgator.com",
        "to": "shanghai",
        "travelDate": "09/06/2022",
        "trainNumber": 1234
      },
      {
        "_id": 5,
        "domainName": "test5.com",
        "hosting": "aws.amazon.com",
        "to": "wuhan",
        "travelDate": "09/06/2022",
        "trainNumber": 1234
      },
      {
        "_id": 6,
        "domainName": "test6.com",
        "hosting": "cloud.google.com",
        "to": "nanjing",
        "travelDate": "09/06/2022",
        "trainNumber": 123
      },
      {
        "_id": 7,
        "domainName": "test7.com",
        "hosting": "aws.amazon.com",
        "to": "nanjing",
        "travelDate": "09/02/2022",
        "trainNumber": 123
      },
      {
        "_id": 8,
        "domainName": "test8.com",
        "hosting": "hostgator.com",
        "to": "nanjing",
        "travelDate": "09/02/2022",
        "trainNumber": 123
      },
      {
        "_id": 9,
        "domainName": "test9.com",
        "hosting": "cloud.google.com",
        "to": "nanjing",
        "travelDate": "09/02/2022",
        "trainNumber": 123
      },
      {
        "_id": 10,
        "domainName": "test10.com",
        "hosting": "godaddy.com",
        "to": "nanjing",
        "travelDate": "09/02/2022",
        "trainNumber": 123
      }
    ]
```

I am using the following query to get the filed **to** as a list of string

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    travelDate: {
      $eq: "09/06/2022"
    },
    trainNumber: {
      $eq: 1234
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "",
    destStations: {
      $push: "$to"
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0
  }
})
```

The above query returns the following result as expected:

```
[
  {
    "destStations": [
      "shanghai",
      "wuhan"
    ]
  }
]
```

But when I am trying to convert it using the following spring mongo aggregation I cannot get the appropriate result. Can anyone help?

```
        Aggregation agg = newAggregation(                match(Criteria.where("travelDate").is(travelDate).and("trainNumber").is(trainNumber)),
                group("id").push("to").as("destStations"),
                project().andExclude("id")
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by `id`, in your spring mongo aggregation, but in your query it's you are grouping on `""` empty string. That's why the results might be varying.

Try passing no argument to `group` function, like this:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("travelDate").is(travelDate).and("trainNumber").is(trainNumber)),
                group().push("to").as("destStations"),
                project().andExclude("id")
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried that already but it provides the following result-
`
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "destStations": [
      "nanjing",
      "beijing",
      "shanghai",
      "nanjing",
      "nanjing"
    ]
  }
]
`
How can I remove the `"_id": null` part

Comment: In project and exclude, part provide `_id`, rather than `id`.